# Use class annotation to run on class initialization with Spring AOP

Tags: java, annotations, spring-aop

Is it possible to create a Java aspect that runs on class initialization using Spring AOP?

We have an annotation that will be used in several places, and in order to make use of the annotation we need some boilerplate code that needs to run every second (using `@Scheduled`). We're hoping to move that boilerplate code to another class-level annotation to make it easier to reuse.

As far as I understand, it's not possible to implement such a class-level annotation using Spring AOP since it only supports method execution (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-vs-aspectj#4-joinpoints). Is there any workaround to achieve what we're hoping for? I'm aware we could use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP, but I'm reluctant to do that because it's complex to use.

Code snipped:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${app.pollable-consumer.time-interval}")
  public void pollForDeletionRequest() {
    log.trace("Polling for new messages");
    cleanupInput.poll(cleanupSubmissionService::submitDeletion);
  }
```

Thanks for your help.

---

**Update:** The annotation needs to be added to a library to enable it to be shared by different microservices.

Comment: Despite Mark's comment, my answer would be: What you want is AspectJ. The article you quoted told you so and you also mentioned it. If you want to weild more power, you need to learn to weild a more powerful weapon. The good news is that AspectJ is pretty easy to use with or without Spring and that the Spring manual describes how to configure it via LTW (load-time weaving) for usage from within Spring. You could even combine both if you use compile-time weaving for your special aspect that needs to run during class initialisation and then Spring AOP for the remainder of aspects.

Comment: Thanks for your input. At this stage I agree with you, but will leave the question open for a while longer to see if any alternatives come up.

Answer (score 0):

> We think that writing a new class-level annotation might help. It would run on class initialization, find all methods that are annotated with @PollableStreamListener, and schedule the polling to happen for each of the Kafka topics.

To slightly adjust the terminology and shift the focus, is it acceptable to bind the creation of such a construction to Spring's Application Context initialization? If so, you could create a [Bean Factory Post Processor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) that would have been triggered for each `@PollableStreamListener`.

In a nutshell, BFPP runs before spring creates the beans during the application context initialization. This mechanism allows to "dynamically" create beans that in a runtime will be indistinguishable from those created by spring in a regular way, a kind of hook to the spring initialization lifecycle that you can use here.

So this BFPP and introspect the methods of your interest. Then based on the information found in the annotations / configuration This BFPP could register a Bean Definition per scheduled job of the bean (a class with all the required parameters that you could prepare as a part of the infrastructure). Then spring will read this bean definition and create the beans out of this bean definition as it usually does.

[Here](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-spring-framework-beanfactorypostprocessor.html) you can find an example of how to use this BFPP and more specifically its `registerBeanDefintion` method.

Comment: We're hoping to add the new annotation (if this is achievable) to a library so that it can be reused by different microservices. Would your suggestion be compatible with this approach?

Comment: Of course, it will. Spring will call BFPP for each bean candidate but you'll have to "filter" somehow for which beans to actually call the logic that I've described. So yes, the BFPP will check whether there is an annotation (if-condition, its a usual java code after all) and apply the logic only for those beans that match the criteria (have an annotation in this case). This is how spring does things internally, but there are no reasons to not re-use this approach for your case